# How to load only one Worksheet using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk

Using OpenXML,I need to read large excel file(50 to 100 mbs)  which contains multiple sheets each having heavy data. My input form having a textbox to enter specific sheetname to be read.

Now my question is how to load only specific sheet in memory & read cell values using openxmlreader, so I can get better performance.